# Robocopy not working in php drupal website

Tags: php, command, command-line-interface, drupal-8, robocopy

I was trying to execute a command in PHP code. The command is working fine in command line interface. But I am unable to execute it inside PHP code.
I came to know that robocopy will work only in administrator mode and the folders should be shared in a network. I have done those settings.
So I opened the command line interface as admin.  This is the peace of code which worked in command line interface.

```
     robocopy \\192.168.8.130\drupal\modules\src\Form\ \\192.168.8.140\DDrive\sample\ /mir /copyall /dcopy:T
```

In php I have the following code,

```
     $files = 'robocopy "\\\\192.168.10.135\\drupal-8-bbrx-master\\modules\\contrib\\clearstone_robocopy\\clearstone_robocopy\\src\\Form\\ \\\\192.168.10.136\\DDrive\\sample\\" /mir /copyall /dcopy:T';
     $sync = system($files);
```

I logged as administrator and executed my project. But still no luck.

Comment: are you getting any error message?

Comment: No. No error messages. But it's not copying the files.